# It will take a while for the drug to work out of your system. (sementic)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It will take a while for the drug to work out of your system.

What exactly or literally 'work out of your system' means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "work out of your system" is a somewhat informal way of saying:

> It will take a while for your body to metabolize the drug so that its
> traces are no longer in your system.

But the intent is to indicate that the process of the body eliminating the drug takes some time.